# How to cope with non-gcc compatible code in OS X Yosemite Core headers

Tags: gcc, clang, osx-yosemite

I maintain a mixed C and C++ command line program that needs to run on Linux, Windows, and OS X. I recently upgraded to Yosemite and my OS X build is now failing. The error is:

```
/usr/include/dispatch/object.h:143:15: error: expected identifier or '(' before '^' token
```

[Other folks have run into this bug](https://github.com/andrewgho/movewin-ruby/issues/1).

The line of code that fails is a typedef that uses '^' which is a [non-standard extension providing support for closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)).

The underlying problem seems to be that some Apple standard headers are starting to require Clang specific extensions. Unfortunately our program has a very deep set of dependencies, some of which won't compile under Clang. We've been using the GCC compilers installed via MacPorts. I have a workaround for now: changing the line in the `object.h` header to be GCC compatible. However, hacking up the include files under `/usr/include` sounds to me like asking for trouble.

Can any OS X/Clang gurus suggest more sustainable ways of coping with this problem? Does this limit the future usefulness of GCC on OS X?

Comment: Clang is the only compiler supported by Apple for OS X. GCC is deprecated and unsupported. I would not expect it to keep functioning.

Comment: I fear @VariableLengthCoder is probably mostly correct.

Comment: This gives me the sadz. Oh well, we still are able to build under Snow Leopard for now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just for future visitors, the following should get most headers working with a recent GCC version:

In `dispatch/object.h` change

`typedef void (^dispatch_block_t)(void);`

to

```
#ifdef __clang__
typedef void (^dispatch_block_t)(void);
#else
typedef void* dispatch_block_t;
#endif
```

and in `Availability.h` change

`#elif defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED)`

to

`#elif defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && defined(__clang__)`